# Как правильно поставить линию после заголовка через абсолютное позиционирование и ::after?

Tags: css, вёрстка, scss

В макете есть несколько подобных подзаголовков

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь, образец видно на скрине. Сам заголовок находится в ограничивающем контейнере, а линия после него доходит до правого края экрана. Как я понял линию надо делать через `::after` и абсолютное позиционирование, но у меня эта линия перечеркивает часть заголовка. Подскажите, как ее правильно сверстать. Вот код:

```css
.page-section__suptitle {
  color: #C2C2C2;
  font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
}
.page-section__suptitle::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<h6 class="page-section__suptitle">our services</h6>
```

Comment: Если фон под заголовком однотонный, то просто оберните `our services` в `span` и задайте ему фоновый `background-color`. Так он перекроет линию.

Comment: @Neolot Это работает. Спасибо. Оформите, как ответ, я галочку поставлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если фон под заголовком однотонный, то просто оберните `our services` в `span` и задайте ему фоновый `background-color`. Так он перекроет линию.

```css
.page-section__suptitle {
  color: #C2C2C2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

.page-section__suptitle span {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.page-section__suptitle::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
```

```html
<h6 class="page-section__suptitle"><span>our services</span></h6>
```